# How can I use an executable jar file with a mainClass in python?

Tags: python, jar, subprocess, popen, py4j

I have an executable jar file with a `mainClass`, named `javaGateway`, located in a subpackage repository, named `gateway_server`, which I want to run inside the package root folder, named `gateway_code`, the parent folder of `gateway_server`. I tried to run it but, my script is block when I run it on shell then it works. To find my package by python, I have setup in python env variable.

With:
`java -cp iotcalcul.jar fr.iot.calcul.javaGateway` that works in shell but by calling this in python script, there is a problem.

Comment: Yes, It's similaire issues but when I tried all proposed solutions from there no one is allow me to run my jar through. By calling `subprocess.Popen(cmd)` Where `cmd = ['java', '-jar', 'iotcalcul.jar']`,and trying to get the return code the module blocked.

Comment: Have you tried jython?

Comment: No, Never, I'm using Py4J instead